# Returning a "name" column in place of an ID in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables **teams** and **games** defined below:

```
Teams
teamID Name rank 
-----------------
1       UNC    8
2       Duke   9
3       Cal    5
4       UNLV   12

Games
gameID team1ID team2ID score1 score2
------------------------------------
1         1       2       88     87 
2         3       4       86     85
```

I would like a Query that returns:

```
gameID   team1name   team2name   score1   score2
------------------------------------------------
   1         UNC        Duke        88       87
   2         Cal        UNLV        86       85
```

I've gotten to the point where I could use the results from the statement below, however, I know there has to be a **right** way.

```
SELECT * FROM games INNER JOIN 
    teams ON teams.teamID = games.team1ID 
    OR teams.teamID = games.team2ID
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the `teams` table twice with different alias names

```
SELECT g.gameID, 
       t1.name as team1, 
       t2.name as team2, 
       g.score1, g.score2
FROM games g
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.teamID = g.team1ID 
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t2.teamID = g.team2ID
```

Comment: Thanks this was perfect!